# Como mudar a cor da Navbar de acordo com cada Section?

Tags: jquery, html, css

tudo bem? Então, estou tendo dificildade de mudar a cor de background da NavBar de acordo com cada Section que eu for visitar no Html com ScrollBar através do JQUERY. A Navbar é fixa. O codigo é mais ou menos assim:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
</nav>

<section id="section1" class="section1">
</section>

<section id="section2" class="section2">
</section>
```

Quando o scroll chegar no section 2 a cor da navbar muda. Alguem poderia me ajudar com um código em Jquery que faça isso?

Obrigado desde já :)

Comment: Oi, se a pergunta minha é duplicada me mostra a outra? Quero saber a questão pra minha duvida. vlw chefe